# Angularjs extracting url base using $location

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am using angularjs $location service. How can I get root of my url using this service. like if my current location is

```
http://localhost:8080/xyz#123
```

I want to extract out `http://localhost:8080` or at least `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var protocol = $location.protocol();
var host = $location.host();
var port = $location.port();

var combined = protocol + '://' + host + ':' + port;
```

Comment: Thanks I have implemented the fix. I am thinking to adding new method to $location service named getBaseUrl(), in app.run() method. Will that be right design.

Comment: If it's just for storing the data you might as well put it on `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using only [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location), you can use

```
$location.host() + ":" +  $location.port()
```